# Can I prevent search engines from indexing an entire directory on my website?

Tags: staging

I have a staging site which I use to draft new features, changes and content to my actual website.

I don't want this to get indexed, but I'm hoping for a solution a little easier than having to add the below to every page on my site:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

Can I do this in a way similar to how I added a password to the domain using a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [robots.txt standard](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) is meant for this. Example

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /protected-directory/
```

Search engines will obey this, but of course the content will still be published (and probably more easily discoverable if you put the URL in the robots.txt), so password protection via .htaccess is an option, too.

Comment: I went with password protection.

Answer (score 6):

What you want is a [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

The file should be in your server root and the content should be something like;

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /mybetasite/
```

This will politely ask search indexing services not to index the pages under that directory, which all well behaved search engines will respect.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, `robots.txt` at the site root is the way to go.
To add multiple entries (as the OP suggests), do as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /test_directory_aaa/
Disallow: /test_directory_bbb/
Disallow: /test_directory_ccc/
```

---

Or, to take the `.htpasswd` route:

**In .htaccess, add:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Marty's test directory"
AuthUserFile /test_directory_aaa/.htpasswd
AuthUserFile /test_directory_bbb/.htpasswd
AuthUserFile /test_directory_ccc/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

**In .htpasswd, add:**

```
username1:s0M3md5H4sh1
username2:s0M3md5H4sh2
username3:s0M3md5H4sh3
```

Comment: Does this result in a username and password prompt? I've never heard of .htpasswd before.

Comment: Here are the Apache docs for .htpasswd : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html. The Wikipedia article also contains a similar example as the one given above : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htpasswd.

Answer (score 3):

Put following code in robot.txt which should be in root directory to refuse your entire site from indexing.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called Robots.txt in your public_html directory.

Put the following code in it:

```
    User-agent: * 
    Disallow: /foldername/
```

foldername is the name of the directory you wish to block

Answer (score 0):

Block Specific File for SEO: 
To specify matching the end of a URL, use $. For instance, to block any URLs that end with .xls:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.xls$

Ref:
http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&topic=1724262&ctx=topic