# Would search engines pick up files in IIS folder, that are not linked to any URL, and in Non-Browseable folder

Tags: security, iis, directory, rights

We have an application that is hosted on IIS, and we have specific files in a folder that we do not want any search engine to register.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052083/can-i-prevent-search-engines-from-indexing-an-entire-directory-on-my-website):

```
The robots.txt standard is meant for this. Example

User-agent: *
Disallow: /protected-directory/
```

I understand that this does not necessarily mean that the files won't be indexed.

My question: would the search engines pick up files that do not have any URL leading to those files?
This directory is not browse-able, and there is no link to it.
Am I safe in drop the file there, or would the search engine crawlers pick it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have this link posted somewhere on the Web, and your directory is non-browseable, then crawler will never find this file and will never index it

Comment: thanks Victor, just to confirm , if this folder was set to "Everyone" has read-access, then it would be crawled, even though there were no links to the files?

Comment: It will not be crawled